# Practical use cases for alignof and alignas C++ keywords

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-alignment, memory-layout

I just learnt about `alignof` and `alignas` C++ keywords but I can't think about any practical case where a developer would want to use these keywords.

Does somebody know any practical use case for these keywords?

Comment: [Memory alignment : how to use alignof / alignas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091382/memory-alignment-how-to-use-alignof-alignas)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Memory alignment : how to use alignof / alignas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091382/memory-alignment-how-to-use-alignof-alignas)

Comment: No I don't think it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common use case for the `alignas` specifier is for the scenario where you want to pass multiple objects between different threads through a queue (e.g., an event or task queue) while avoiding [*false sharing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing). False sharing will result from having multiple threads competing for the same *cache line* when they are actually accessing different objects. It is usually undesirable due to performance degradation.

For example – assuming that the cache line size is *64* bytes – given the following `Event` class:

```
struct Event {
   int event_type_;
};
```

The alignment of `Event` will correspond to the alignment of its data member, `event_type_`. Assuming that the alignment of `int` is *4* bytes (i.e., `alignof(int)` evaluates to *4*), then up to *16* `Event` objects can fit into a single cache line. So, if you have a queue like:

```
std::queue<Event> eventQueue;
```

Where one thread pushes events into the back of the queue, and another thread pulls events from the front, we may have both threads competing for the same cache line. However, by properly using the `alignas` specifier on `Event`:

```
struct alignas(64) Event {
   int event_type_;
};
```

This way, an `Event` object will always be aligned on a cache line boundary so that a cache line will contain an `Event` object at most. Therefore two or more threads will never be competing for the same cache line when accessing distinct `Event` objects (if multiple threads are accessing the same `Event` object, they will obviously compete for the same cache line).

Answer (score 2):

Practical use cases from my experience:

- writing specialized allocator for network packets in embedded system
- working around bugs in specialized CPU of embedded system
- performance optimizations regarding cache usage
- providing part of C++ object into C library which expects concrete alignment

Answer (score 1):

**Spare memory on pointers**: if pointers to a type always end in zeros because of alignment of that type, then those always zero bits can be used to store something else. Example:

```
class Small { Aligned * ptr; bool b; }; // suppose having many instances
```

would take at least 8+1 bytes on 64bit architectures, but it can be compressed to 8 bytes by carefully union-ing the ptr and the bool. Before using the ptr you have to bitmask it, but that is a very fast instruction.
Its a trade-off between memory and cpu.

Comment: A compiler is not actually permitted to do this. Pointers are trivial types, so I'm allowed to assign to them by `memcpy`ing into them. This *cannot* be allowed to modify the value of any other object, including `b`. But if these were sharing memory, it would. Padding bytes are part of an object's representation and thus cannot arbitrarily be used by some other object (unless that object is zero-sized).