# Why is Single Threading faster than multi threading in this simple summing program?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing

The Program is summming the first 10,000 integers.

Here's the Single Threaded program

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;

    start = clock();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }

    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("Sum of first 10000 positive integers: %d\n", sum);
    printf("Time taken: %f seconds\n", cpu_time_used);

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the multi threading counterpart ; where i am dividing the work equally among 4 threads

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 4
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10000

int sum = 0;
int partialSums[NUM_THREADS] = {0};

void *calculateSum(void *threadid) {
    long tid;
    tid = (long)threadid;
    int chunkSize = ARRAY_SIZE / NUM_THREADS;
    int start = tid * chunkSize + 1;
    int end = (tid + 1) * chunkSize;

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        partialSums[tid] += i;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    long t;
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;

    start = clock();

    for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++) {
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, calculateSum, (void *)t);
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++) {
        pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        sum += partialSums[i];
    }

    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("Sum of first 10000 positive integers: %d\n", sum);
    printf("Time taken: %f seconds\n", cpu_time_used);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The single threaded program takes on avg 0.000019 sec while the multi threaded program takes around 0.000300 sec

Why is that? And when is multi threaded more performant than single threaded program? When should we use it?

PS: How should I be comparing their execution time because i heard somewhere that using clock spits out erroneous vals sometimes; esp under large loads?

Comment: Since you sum only a few integers (10000 is not that much), the overhead of thread management could be larger than the speedup the 4 threads can provide. Could you test with a much bigger value ? (and have attention to the type of the integer you use -> use uint64_t for instance in order to be sure not to have overflows)

Comment: The biggest issue is that **you are not measuring the wall clock time**, but the parallel CPU time. `clock` must not be used to measure the wall clock time. You should use `gettimeofday` or similar functions instead (possibly `clock_gettime` too but please read the doc).

Comment: Besides, a good optimizing compiler (like Clang) can completely optimize out your function. There is a mathematical analytical expression for computing `1+2+3+...+N` and such compilers know that and use it instead of the slow loop. This benchmark is completely biased.

Comment: The usual remark about questions like this: it is complete nonsense to benchmark code without optimizations enabled. So if that's what you are doing, you have much bigger problems than whether or not to use parallelism.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is quite self-evident: You're trying to parallelize a problem whose single threaded solution is faster than the overhead you incur through parallelization.

That is the *usual* case. Think about it: 10,000 integers for a 2 GHz CPU which can typically achieve a throughput of 1 integer instruction per clock cycle¹, that's is going to take but 10,000 / (2 GHz) = 5 µs, in addition to memory access overhead. Often, the overhead and uncertainty in getting the current time for your benchmarking is significantly large compared to the time your computation takes!

Starting a new thread takes longer than 5 µs; communicating using multi-writer-safe structures or cross-core atomics between threads (which is what `pthread_join` needs to do) takes longer.

Parallelism at that granularity makes no sense. Get a bigger problem! For example, if you had a hundred million integers coming in every second and do more than just summation (that is really the order of magnitude, we do this in software-defined radio) on your application processor (i.e, intel, AMD or modern ARM processor), then it might start making sense "deinterleaving" summation in multiple-of-cache-line-size chunks to multiple processor cores if you're aiming for performance. Note that for the simple addition case, your problem is usually not CPU performance, but memory bandwidth, so that even in a perfect world with zero communication overhead *you couldn't speed up summation by distributing it across multiple CPU cores*; the CPU cores are not the bottleneck.

Generally, you usually *don't* parallelize elementary instructions; that's terrible for cache locality: assuming you want to do some other operation on these numbers before summation (say, divide them by some other number), you would then have intermediary results that you need to shuffle between cores.

---

¹ "throughput" means here: how many operations does my CPU finish on average when doing this, per clock cycle. That's a different measure to how many cycles it takes for an instruction to finish, because CPUs have *pipelines*, i.e. why the first still computes, the next is still being worked on (in fact, it's typically much more than 2 instructions). 
Note that 1 integer summation per cycle is a *very* conservative estimate. Modern x86_64 CPUs do a "add this pair of eight 32-bit integers" (`_mm256_add_epi32`) with a throughput of 3, meaning you get 8 summations 3 times per cycle, i.e. at 2 GHz 48 billion additions per second. (You can't achieve that, as far as I can tell) Roughly like this [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5rx61WrcY); running on a contested shared cloud computer, it takes 0.1 s to 0.5 s to compute your program for the sum up to 1 billion, using 64 bit unsigned integers (because that sum won't fit in a 32 bit integer); so on that public system, your example with sufficiently large problem size achieves 2 to 10 billion counter increments and summations per second. 
Note that you must have compiled without optimization; because as soon as you turn on optimization on a modern compiler, it will just compute the result at compile time, and not even implement the for loop in machine code. I had to add a dependency on an external factor to stop the compiler from doing that precompution!

Comment: *"with a throughput of 1/3, meaning you get 8 summations every 3 cycles"* No. It is 3 instructions per cycle (thanks to ILP). Intel CPU can do 3 VPADDD instruction/cycle since at least Skylake. Same for Zen2 for AMD CPUs and Zen3/Zen4 can do 4 of them per cycle. Thus, it is 48e9 additions/s though note that the frequency can change when AVX instructions are executed on some rare CPUs (due to the power consumption of such units).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I got my numbers from the intel intrinsics guide, which lists a latency as 1 and the throughput as 0.33 on Skylake; maybe I'm reading that table incorrectly? EDIT: Yes, I do; the intel "throughput" notation is "CPI", which probably means cycles per instruction.

Comment: Also please note that your demo do not use AVX but SSE2 because SSE2 is used by default by GCC for sake of compatibility. One need to add the flag `-mavx2` to fix that. The code generated is unfortunately sub-optimal (since it is not automatically unrolled and the reduction is not great either -- saturating the port5 on Intel CPUs).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I used `-mnative`, because I don't know whether the VM the godbolt GCC explorer runs in actually supports AVX2, and I wanted to be able to run the code I generated.

Comment: 0.33 is right, but it means 3 of the instruction can be executed per cycle, not the opposite. A value of 3 would mean 1 instruction every 3 cycles. I admit this is not very intuitive. You means `-march=native` ? `-mnative` does not seem recognized by GCC. AFAIK Godbolt runs on CPU supporting AVX-512.

Comment: @JérômeRichard thanks for pointing it out, I would have missed it! fixed the answer in that regard (but used my definition of throughput, not intel's)

Comment: There is also this sentence to fix ;) : "in the range of 2 to 10 billion summations per second"

Answer (score 0):

Parallelization has overhead in many ways. One is that it takes time for the operating system to start a thread, switch between threads, and terminate threads. If your single-threaded program takes less time than the constant time of starting threads, then the single-threaded program will be faster.

Another problem is the overhead of sharing memory between threads. If two or more threads need to access the same memory, then you'll need some synchronization which takes time. Here you don't have or need any synchronization, but since the CPU is loading memory in *cache lines*, you'll get something that's called ["False sharing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766191/what-is-false-sharing-how-to-reproduce-avoid-it). This is most likely what's happening here since all threads are trying to read and write from `int partialSums[NUM_THREADS]`, which are all most likely in the same cache line.

Comment: Fun fact : with optimizations (`-O3`), GCC does not actually read/store `partialSums` in the loop. It does the whole computation in registers. As for Clang, it just optimizes the whole loop out to few instructions which is even faster (i.e. no loop anymore). In the end, there is *no false-sharing* on both GCC and Clang.

Answer (score 0):

Because: optimization.

When getting rid of your benchmarking code and running it in gcc with full optimizations, then the generated assembler looks like this:

```
mov     esi, 50005000
```

And that's it. The loop is completely removed and the result is calculated at compile-time. If you however tell the compiler to run off and create a bunch of threads, that will be many hundreds of times less efficient.